# How can I programmatically select a listview item?

Tags: elm

How can I programmatically select a listview item?

I have the following listview:

```
listview =
    select [ Html.Events.on "change" (Json.Decode.map InputContentType Html.Events.targetValue) ]
        [ option [ value "instructions" ] [ text "Content Type" ]
        , option [ value "Article" ] [ text "Article" ]
        , option [ value "Video" ] [ text "Video" ]
        , option [ value "Answer" ] [ text "Answer" ]
        , option [ value "Podcast" ] [ text "Podcast" ]
        ]
```

**Update:**

I incorporated the posted answer below and updated the solution as follows:

```
( isArticle, isVideo, isAnswer, isPodcast ) =
            if hasText "youtube.com" then
                ( False, True, False, False )
            else if hasText "vimeo.com" then
                ( False, True, False, False )
            else if hasText "wordpress.com" then
                ( True, False, False, False )
            else if hasText "medium.com" then
                ( True, False, False, False )
            else if hasText "stackoverflow.com" then
                ( False, False, True, False )
            else
                ( False, False, False, False )

        listview =
            select [ Html.Events.on "change" (Json.Decode.map InputContentType Html.Events.targetValue) ]
                [ option [ value "instructions" ] [ text "Content Type" ]
                , option [ value "Article", selected isArticle ] [ text "Article" ]
                , option [ value "Video", selected isVideo ] [ text "Video" ]
                , option [ value "Answer", selected isAnswer ] [ text "Answer" ]
                , option [ value "Podcast", selected isPodcast ] [ text "Podcast" ]
                ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to use the `Html.Attributes.selected` function to select programmatically one of the `option`s. It accepts a `Bool`, so whenever it's `True`, it will select that `option`.

```
listview =
    select [ Html.Events.on "change" (Json.Decode.map InputContentType Html.Events.targetValue) ]
        [ option [ value "instructions" ] [ text "Content Type" ]
        , option [ value "Article", selected True ] [ text "Article" ]
        , option [ value "Video" ] [ text "Video" ]
        , option [ value "Answer" ] [ text "Answer" ]
        , option [ value "Podcast" ] [ text "Podcast" ]
        ]
```